# Using poetry and pip to install dependencies with private repositories

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

We are currently using poetry for developing our python packages. Since we do have a private artifactory we have the following `pyproject.toml` things set:

```ini
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "main-private-artifactory"
url = "https://xx.yy"
default = true


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "special-private-arti"
url = "https://xx.mm"
```

Which works well when using poetry. No outgoing calls and it finds the packages quite fine. just for completeness sake the special package is specified like this in the `.toml` file:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
special-package = {version = "^1.0.0", source = "special-private-arti"}
```

Now since pip should support installing from a `pyproject.toml` I created a new venv and tried to install our packages dependencies by executing:

```
pip install . -vv
```

in the same directory where `pyproject.toml` resides. I have a few problems with that:

1. When looking at the verbose output it shows pip is calling `https://pypi.org/simple` which should be a BIG nono according to my `pyproject.toml` file.
2. It does not find the special package since it ignores my defined sources

Anyone have an approach I can try other than changing back to `venv` and `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that using the `-i`/`--index-url` of pip helps, when your private pypi server redirects also to pypi.org/simple.

So, as a workaround, for me this worked:

```bash
pip install . -vv -i https://xx.mm
```

Comment: Sadly no solution found as of yet. I was forced to drop it from all our projects because we need to work with private artifactory. Once this is solved then i might be able to convince my peers to switch back.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
poetry run pip3 install [pkg name] [-i] [url]
```